# Fedena installation in windows with ruby & rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, command, fedena

I am trying to install Fedena open sourse into my windows Have follow all the steps in fedena and wiki but still i am getting error Please help me here is my command lines and I am following this link of fedena http://projectfedena.org/install   in these Getting error in "bundle install --local" Here is the Commands windows

```
    C:\Users\Devil>cd c:\Fedena

c:\Fedena>bundle install --local
Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
You have requested:
  mysql = 2.8.1

The bundle currently has mysql locked at 2.8.1.
Try running `bundle update mysql`

If you are updating multiple gems in your Gemfile at once,
try passing them all to `bundle update`

c:\Fedena>bundle update mysql
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from http://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 0.8.7
Using activesupport 2.3.5
Using rack 1.0.1
Using cgi_multipart_eof_fix 2.5.0
Using daemons 1.2.4
Using declarative_authorization 0.5.1
Installing fastthread 1.0.7 with native extensions
Using fattr 2.2.1
Using gem_plugin 0.2.3
Using i18n 0.4.2
Installing mysql 2.8.1 with native extensions
Installing win32-open3 0.3.2 with native extensions
Using bundler 1.14.3
Using activerecord 2.3.5
Using activeresource 2.3.5
Using actionpack 2.3.5
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/fastthread-1.0.7/ext/fastthread
C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170201-7960-vtf9xv.rb extconf.rb
extconf.rb:13:in `block in <main>': uninitialized constant Config (NameError)
Did you mean?  RbConfig
        from extconf.rb:12:in `open'
        from extconf.rb:12:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/fastthread-1.0.7 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/fastthread-1.0.7/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing fastthread (1.0.7), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install fastthread -v '1.0.7'` succeeds before bundling.

c:\Fedena>gem install fastthread -v '1.0.7'
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing fastthread:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/fastthread-1.0.7/ext/fastthread
C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170201-3752-fbqr51.rb extconf.rb
extconf.rb:13:in `block in <main>': uninitialized constant Config (NameError)
Did you mean?  RbConfig
        from extconf.rb:12:in `open'
        from extconf.rb:12:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/fastthread-1.0.7 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/fastthread-1.0.7/gem_make.out

c:\Fedena>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just completed my installation successfully. Below are steps I followed:

```
sudo gem install bundler

bundle install --local

gem install rails -v 2.3.5
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev mysql-server
gem install rake -v 0.8.7
gem install declarative_authorization -v 0.5.1
gem install i18n -v 0.4.2
gem install mysql
gem install rush -v 0.6.8
gem update --system 1.3.7

rake db:create
rake db:migrate

rake fedena:plugins:install_all
```

Launch with script/server

Make sure your **ruby version is 1.8.7** and rake is 0.8.7

To install ruby 1.8.7 and set as default:

```
rvm install 1.8.7
rvm use 1.8.7 --default
```